# Visual Studio: Conditionally Create Shortcuts in Setup Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project

I am working on a Setup Project in Visual Studio, and I would like the user to be able to specify whether to create a Desktop Shortcut and/or a Start Menu shortcut to the program by using checkboxes.

I am able to have the installer to create working shortcuts in the appropriate locations, and I added a dialog containing checkboxes to the installer; however, I am unable to have the creation (or lack thereof) of these shortcuts connected to the status of these checkboxes.

I'm assuming that I need to set "Condition" properties, but I'm not sure of the specific syntax. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Look here [Microsoft Forum](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=431596) for a reply from Microsoft in April of this year covering the same problem as yours.

Comment: Hmm, that's most unfortunate; but that's a pretty definitive answer. Thanks.

Comment: oh ahaha I was looking that that page but It does not exist anymore :D

Answer (score 9):

The linked feedback item said:

> In the case that you want the checkbox to only control whether the shortcut installs, and not its target, there is currently no solution **in Visual Studio setup projects**, and this is best accomplished either through extra MSI knowledge and a post-build script to manually modify your MSI after each build, or by migrating to a more advanced (and flexible) tool for setup development (for example, Windows Installer XML).

You can't do it within the VS point-and-click interface, but 
it's actually not difficult to do what you want with a simple custom action.

[image]

Define a script, in VBScript or JavaScript. You can set the custom action to run based on any condition, including a checkbox in a dialog.

[image]

Inside the script, you parse the input, and create the shortcut.  I used the convention to separate args to the script with a | character, so this is how I parse:

```
var parameters = Session.Property("CustomActionData").split("|"); 
var targetDir = parameters[0];
var checkBoxState = parameters[1];
```