Creating an Application Installation File Created by C#
I created a setup file using the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer.
The installation file was successfully installed, and I would like to add one process here.
After the installation is completed, I want to allow the user to decide whether to create a shortcut to the desktop and startup program through the check box at the end.
When Microsoft Visual Studio Installer sets shortcuts to be created on desktop and startup programs, shortcuts are created before the installation is complete and the last dialog is created.
If I create an installation file through Advanced Installer, NSIS, Install Shield, etc., can I configure the user selection box dialog at the end after the installation is complete?

You can't with VS Installer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538211/visual-studio-conditionally-create-shortcuts-in-setup-project Use Wix instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658220/create-shortcut-checkbox

The shortcuts are created much earlier in the installation process, that is why usually the shortcuts dialog is visible in first stages.
When the last dialog is displayed the installation is already installed, including the shortcuts. That dialog is just to inform the user on the progress of the installation, not to customize it.
If you want to display such an option at the end you will need to write your own custom action to create (or delete an existing) shortcut. IMHO you are complicating the installer without much returns, just use the predefined support/dialogs offered by tools like Advanced Installer or Installshield.
